# Trying to get property 'id_usuario' of non-object al pasar un dato del controlador a la vista

Tags: php, bootstrap, codeigniter

es la primera vez que pregunto por este medio, estoy comenzando a aprender PHP con CodeIgniter para la realización de un proyecto.
Estoy intentando efectuar la lectura de los datos de un usuario determinado en mi base de datos, y mostrar esos datos en un formulario. Para el ejemplo solo trato de mostrar el ID y el DNI.
El error que me arroja es:
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property 'id_usuario' of non-object
Filename: persona/vact_admbus.php

Mi modelo es:

```
public function buscarAdmin($id_bus,$dni_bus)
{
    $this->db->select('p.dni,p.nombre,p.apellido,p.fecha_nac,p.telefono,p.direccion,p.pais,p.provincia,p.ciudad,p.correo,p.id_usuario,p.clave');
    $this->db->from('personas p');
    $this->db->where('p.id_usuario',$id_bus);
    $resultado = $this->db->get();
    return $resultado->result();
}
```

Mi controlador es:

```
public function buscarAdmin() 
{
    $id_bus = $this->input->post('txtUsuario');
    $dni_bus = $this->input->post('txtDNI');

    $data['info_usuarios'] = $this->mpersona->buscarAdmin($id_bus,$dni_bus);

    $this->load->view('layout/header');
    $this->load->view('layout/menu');
    $this->load->view('persona/vact_admbus', $data);
    $this->load->view('layout/footer'); 
}
```

Y la vista es:

```
 <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/cpersona/buscarAdmin" method="POST"">      
            <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">

              <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Usuario</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">

                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtUsuario" value="<?= $info_usuarios->id_usuario; ?>" placeholder="Usuario" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Usuario">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">DNI</label>

              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtDNI" value="<?= $info_usuarios->dni; ?>" placeholder="DNI" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="DNI">
              </div>
            </div>
             </div>
           </div>
```

Ahí edite, poniendo el texto del código como me sugirieron, disculpen la demora, me costo agarrarle la mano a la identación del código.
El archivo vact_admbus.php es la vista.
Desde ya, muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Por favor cambia las imágenes por el texto del código. Con imágenes se complica copiar alguna parte del código para reproducir el problema y su contenido es difícil de ver en dispositivos pequeños. Puedes editar la pregunta para hacer el cambio. Gracias. De paso, dinos cuál de los tres es el archivo `vact_admbus.php`

Comment: El resultado de su método `buscarAdmin`, retorna un array de objetos, pero en su vista intenta acceder como si fuese un objeto simple, quizá debería iterar con un `forEach` o revisar el método  `row_array()` u otro que retorne un objeto  simple.